# Hibernate: Получение древовидной структуры

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть таблица, замапленная через Hibernate.

В этой таблице существует неограниченное на данный момент количество категорий, многие из которых имеют "родителей" (если в столбце parent_id стоит id категории).

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
Category={id=10, name="Category_1", parentId=5};
```

- что подразумевает, что родителем для категории 10 является категория 5.

Структура древовидная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, на данный момент, существует неограниченная вложенность категорий.

Также, в проекте используется QueryDsl.

Существует ли возможность вытащить список всех категорий-наследников для конкретной категории?

Comment: Неужели нет такой возможности?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл на просторах интернета следующее решение:

https://www.tikalk.com/java/load-tree-jpa-and-hibernate/

Там это решено так:

```
public Node getTree(){ 
  entityManager.createNamedQuery
    ("findAllNodesWithTheirChildren").getResultList(); 
   Node root = entityManager.find(Node.class, ROOT_ID); 
   return root;
}
```